# Fetch data from xml in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

in my xml file there is field like this:

```
<state-code>GA</state-code>
```

now i am fetching data from it in php.
simplexml_load_file is returning the whole content as object.
no problem still now ,but when i am writing like this

```
$single_property->location->state-code
```

it is not fetching value.
but if it is  or  then no problem.but i don't have control over the xml file structure.have to find out another way.
what to do?please suggest.

Comment: Please give more information. Can you `var_dump` the result of the XML parsing ?

Comment: please provide a sample XML

Comment: `it is not fetching value. but if it is or then no problem` can you please explain that  again?

Comment: Did you give up on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all other code not shown is correct, you access a property with illegal chars (the -)  like:

```
$single_property->location->{'state-code'}
```